# Click on link to show page loader, then make page loader disappear after a defined time, the show destination's url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm quite new concerning javascript and I have a problem that seems too simple but it's giving me trouble.
I have a link and I want to achieve that when I click on the link, an invisible page loader appears, then I want the page loader to disappear after a determined amount of time, and finally that it goes to the url of the link.
It's important that it happens on the page before, I don't want the div to be shown onload.

I've tried several extra scripts "setTimeout", "prevent" to hide the loader after a while but it doesn't work... it simply disappears as soon as the page finishes loading.
This is so far the cleanest point I've come to.

```
    <a class="#" href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('page-loader').style.display='block';"></a>
```

```
#page-loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0%;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 250px;
    background-color: black; 
}
```

I hope you can help me out with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much on track! When you click a link, you'll need to show the `loader` div. You've got the CSS defined, and just need to modify the `display` value to show it (either through `style.display` or applying another `class` which overrides the `display: none`).

Using `setTimeout`, you can then define a callback to hide the div and navigate.

Here's an example (hides loader after a second, and then navigates after a half second):

```js
// Bind our our click event listener
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    // Calling preventDefault will prevent the browser from navigating (prevents the default behavior)
    e.preventDefault();

    // Our defined link, where we want to navigate to
    const destination = this.getAttribute('href');

    // Our loader div - we'll set to a const to reference later
    const loader = document.querySelector('#page-loader');

    // On click, we immediately want to show our loading div.
    // For this demo, we'll use style.display to override our CSS
    loader.style.display = 'block';
    
    // Set Timeout - We've defined a 1 second delay
    setTimeout(function () {

        // After 1 second, we want to hide the loader. Again, using style, we set to 'none'
        loader.style.display = 'none';

        // One additional set timeout - this allows the browser time to hide the loader. I've defined a half second
        setTimeout(function () {

              // This will set the URL to our href
              window.location.href = destination;
        }, 500);
    }, 1000);
})
```

```css
#page-loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0%;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 250px;
    background-color: black; 
}
```

```html
<div id="page-loader">Loading</div>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

One suggestion: I would avoid using `href="#"` as a way to avoid navigating. Call `e.preventDefault` to prevent the browser from immediately navigating to the destination. That way, if JavaScript is disabled/blocked or broken, the link will still work.

Happy learnings!

Comment: Your snippet seems to work correctly, but my software says there's a syntax error where the first setTimeout appears. And the result it gives me is that it jumps right away to the url without showing the loader...

Comment: As for the href="#"... I just wrote it like that to not show the actual url, so no worries.

Comment: Hi @Manuel, it's probably the use of the `arrow` function. I'll update the answer to use the traditional `function` declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much Jack! This code works amazing! And I really appreciate your time to even explain how it works. I just had to modify it to the class of my link and voilá. I made also some research in the meanwhile you answered and found out another code that works great, perhaps it can help others as well: $('a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();                  
var goTo = this.getAttribute("href"); 
setTimeout(function(){
window.location = goTo;
}, 3000);
});

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const nav = () => {
var loader = document.getElementById('loader');
loader.style.display='block';
setTimeout(()=>loader.style.display = 'none', 3000);
}
```

```css
#loader{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='loader'>Loading...</div>
<a href='#' onClick='nav()'>Change</a>
```

Comment: Your snippet seems to work correctly, but my software says there's a syntax error on the first line. And the result it gives me is the same... it shows the loader only until the page finishes loading.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<script>
document.getElementById("page-loader").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("page-loader").style.display='block';

});
<script>
```

Comment: If the default display of `page-loader` is `none`, you won't be able to click on it in order to trigger an event click to change the `display` to `block`